# Cannot use basic authentication while serving static files using express

Tags: node.js, express, basic-authentication

Using the Express framework for node.js, I'm trying to serve up static files contained in a directory while also putting basic authentication on it. When I do so, I am prompted for the username and password (as expected), but after I correctly enter them, I'm given a 404. If I remove the authentication check and serve up the same directory, I actually get the pages contained within it.

Here's a quick server I whipped up as a proof-of-concept:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

var auth = express.basicAuth(function(user,pass) {
  return 'user' === user && 'pass' === pass;
});

app.use('/admin', auth, express.static(__dirname + '/admin'));
app.use('/adminNoAuth', express.static(__dirname + '/admin'));

app.listen(8082);
```

When I hit `localhost:8082/admin` I get the username/password, then a 404. When I hit `localhost:8082/adminNoAuth` it serves up the page.

I'm using Express 3.4.7 and node.js 0.10.22.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`app.use` doesn't let you chain middlewares in that way.  The various `app.VERB` functions do, but `app.use` doesn't.  That's for one middleware at a time.

If you split the 2 middlewares out into separate calls, you should get the results you want:

```
app.use('/admin', auth)
app.use('/admin', express.static(__dirname + '/admin'));
```

**EDIT**

As of express version `4.x` you can pass in multiple middlewares as an array, or arguments, or mixture of both into `app.use`. Making static files authorization safe would now be:

```
app.use( "/admin", [ auth, express.static( __dirname + "/admin" ) ] );
```

But both ways are still perfectly valid.

Answer (score 4):

The answer:

```
var express = require("express")
var ss = require("serve-static")
var ba = require("basic-auth")
var app = express()
app.use("/", ss(__dirname + "/public"))
app.use(entry)
app.use("/privatesite", ss(__dirname + "/private"))
app.listen(4000)  

function entry(req, res, next) {
    var objUser = ba(req)
    if (objUser === undefined || objUser.name !== "john" || objUser.pass !== "1234") {
        res.set("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=Authorization Required")
        res.status(401).end()
    } else { next() }
}
```

The 1st app.use() line offers the content of "public" folder in x.x.x.x:4000 ("/" route) to all visitors. The 3rd app.use() line offers the content of "private" folder in x.x.x.x:4000/privatesite ("/privatesite" route) only to user "john" because this line is written after 2nd app.use() line, which loads the authentication middleware. This authentication middleware uses "basic-auth" component, which returns an object with the name and pass written by client. If it is not "john" and "1234", server returns a 401 page; if it is, continue (thanks to next()) to 3rd app.use() line

Comment: Mind to give some explanation?

Comment: The 1st app.use() line offers the content of "public" folder in http://x.x.x.x:4000 ("/" route) to all visitors. The 3rd app.use() line offers the content of "private" folder in http://x.x.x.x:4000/privatesite ("/privatesite" route) only to user "john" because this line is written after 2nd app.use() line, which loads the authentication middleware. This authentication middleware uses "basic-auth" component, which returns an object with the name and pass written by client. If it is not "john" and "1234", server returns a 401 page; if it is, continue (thanks to next()) to 3rd app.use() line

Comment: Use this info to edit your answer. It will make it a better one.

Comment: Exactly what I needed :)

Comment: you wont need serve-static, express has this built in

Answer (score 1):

I thought I'd post the express 4 answer here, since there's no other post title as fitting as this one for this specific use-case, and it may be relevant for more people.

If you're using express 4, chances are you're using serve-index, serve-static, and http-auth (unless there's an easier way that I'm missing out on):

```
serveIndex = require('serve-index'),
serveStatic = require('serve-static'),
auth = require('http-auth');     

// Basic authentication
var basic = auth.basic({
        realm: "My Secret Place.",
    }, function (username, password, callback) { // Custom authentication method.
        callback(username === "me" && password === "mepassword");
    }
);

var authMiddleware = auth.connect(basic);

// Serve /secretplace as a directory listing
app.use('/secretplace', authMiddleware, serveIndex(__dirname + '/public/secretplace'));

// Serve content under /secretplace as files
app.use('/secretplace', serveStatic(__dirname + '/public/secretplace', { 'index': false }));
```

Note, as far as my testing, I didn't need to pass 'authMiddleware' when setting serveStatic.

Answer (score 0):

Im sharing how it worked out for me.

```
app.use("/login", (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.cookies.UUID) {
    res.redirect("/app");
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
app.use("/login", express.static("dist_auth_app"));
app.use("/app", (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.cookies.UUID) {
    res.redirect("/login");
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
app.use("/app", express.static("dist"));
```