# How to protect static folder in express with passport

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I have a project based on express with a required authentication based on passport.

The backoffice is an angularjs app served as static files.

My authentication code is completly based on https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/blob/master/examples/express3-no-connect-flash/app.js

To do not serve the angular app if you are not authenticated. I have try by adding ensureAuthenticated on the /admin route but it make the route not working (404). Once I remove ensureAuthenticated the /admin is served.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/admin', ensureAuthenticated, express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'admin')));
//serve routes
app.use(app.router);
```

The public folder contains the login page.

How could I achieve this ?

Comment: Could you use middleware (connect) to redirect to login if they hit the `/admin` route when not logged in?

Comment: This is what I'm trying to do but without success. ensureAuthenticated redirect to login if not. But with this, it works when not loggedin, but when logged in I have a 404 on /admin

Comment: I was thinking more of the `app.use(function(req, res, next) { if (!req.user)... }`

Comment: It works so you should post an full answer I will mark it as valid. And thanks, the idea was to create a middleware instead of trying to chains the calls into app.use

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can check the route using middleware and redirect them if they aren't logged in and are hitting admin pages, something like (untested):

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.user == null && req.path.indexOf('/admin') === 0)
    {
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
    next(); 
});
```

Comment: This does not work for me. When a folder is on a static path, it seems it does not go through the app.use route.

Comment: Your answer would have been clearer to a newbie like me if you added below the other `app.use` with the 'static' part (called by that `next()`), like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36446697/382515). I'm learning express, passport, promises, etc. all at the same time. Thanks anyway.

Comment: this is a nice way of doing an authorization check before any other call, just be careful with one thing after calling `res.redirect` this function should return just in case the next function is some kind of API call and tries to set headers or do any other thing to the request.

Answer (score 40):

Ran into same issue, this is what I ended up doing!

> app.use doesn't let you chain middlewares in that way. The various
>   app.VERB functions do, but app.use doesn't. That's for one middleware
>   at a time.
>
> If you split the 2 middlewares out into separate calls, you should get
>   the results you want:

```
app.use('/admin', ensureAuthenticated);
app.use('/admin', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'admin')));
```

[Cannot use basic authentication while serving static files using express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170253/cannot-use-basic-authentication-while-serving-static-files-using-express/21170931#21170931)

Comment: From the source above : @Mathias made and edit - As of express version 4.x you can pass in multiple middlewares as an array, or arguments, or mixture of both into app.use. Making static files authorization safe would now be:

Answer (score 13):

```
app.use('/admin', function(req,res,next){
 if(req.user){
   return express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'));
 } else {
   res.render(403, 'login', {message:'Please, login!'});
 }
});

//serve routes
app.use(app.router);
```

Comment: The answer looks reasonable, but some explanation about why it works would help.

Comment: for route '/admin' we mount middleware, defined by anonymous function, that returns static middleware, if user object exists in request object, or stop the request processing by rendering 403 page with login form.

Comment: Didn't work for me, request was just stuck with no response! Also app.use(app.router); is removed in express 4.x

Comment: You need to call the function returned by express.static with the current context `return express.static(dir)(req,res,next);`

Answer (score 4):

Update for `express@4.16.4+`, `passport-jtw@0.4.0`, and `passport-jwt@4.0.0`

First setup a passport auth strategy. If you use a jwt, you can take a token from a query parameter, if not you can use another Extract function (or multiple using `Jwt.ExtractJwt.fromExtractors()`)

```
passport.use('basic-user',
    new Jwt.Strategy({
        ...jwtConfig.options,
        jwtFromRequest: Jwt.ExtractJwt.fromUrlQueryParameter('token')
    }, verifyUser)
);
```

Then you can use a passport authenticate function before serving static files

```
app.use('/files', [
    passport.authenticate(['basic-user'], { session: false }),
    express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'files')) //make sure you access proper directory
])
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also chain middlewares as an array to achieve this goal:

```js
app.use('/admin', [ensureAuthenticated, express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'admin'))]);
```

Comment: this is what helped me, since having a separate `app.use('/admin', ensureAuthenticated);` does not work from express v4

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer felt a bit partial (and may not work in some cases), so here's a bit more verbose and generalized answer:

```
// Here we'll attach the user object. The correct ordering 
// of these middleware functions is important.
app.use(
  '/some-restricted-static-path',
  passport.authenticate("bearer", { session: false })
);

// As the user object should now be attached (if authorized), we can now
// verify it to be so.
app.use('/some-restricted-static-path', (req, res, next) => {
  if (!!req.user) {
    // The user exists, we can continue.
    // Here you can also validate the role etc if necessary.
    next();
  } else {
    // No user object found, terminate the pipeline with .end().
    res.status(401).end();
  }
});

// And finally, here's the actual handler that won't be accessed if 
// something went wrong earlier.
app.use(
  '/some-restricted-static-path',
  express.static(
    path.join(
      __dirname,
      "../dist/attachments"
    )
  )
);
```

Explanation: In Express, the middleware is processed one-by-one. If one of the middleware terminate the process, every middleware after it will be skipped. So, knowing this, we can first attach the user object, then validate it, and finally either grant or deny access.