# Expressjs remove static folder

Tags: node.js, express

I have nodejs webpage and i am using expressjs. I have few static folders and with user log out i have to remove some of them. Below is how i add static folder, i am not using any options maybe that is the problem.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

And i need something like below:

```
app.use(express.removeStatic(__dirname + '/public'));
```

or

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public',{vissible: false}));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21335868/how-to-protect-static-folder-in-express-with-passport/21341638#21341638

Comment: @vodolaz095 this post ask about route not static folder

Comment: question i mentioned was about approach of making public folder accessible only by authenticated users

Comment: @vodolaz095 Answer to that question does not cover mine question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As described [here](http://expressjs.com/api.html#middleware) the `express.static` middleware is based on [serve-static](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static). There is no way of removing already loaded middleware (static files).

What I would suggest is creating your own **serve-static** middleware. You can use [this](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static/blob/master/index.js) as reference then just load the session middleware before the serve-static middleware then add an option that checks if the session data is available, if not then don't serve.

The basic idea is something like:

```
  return function serveStatic(req, res, next) {
    if (req.method !== 'GET' && req.method !== 'HEAD') {
      return next()
    }
    // add this
    if (req.session.loggedIn === false) {
      return next()
    }
```

### Example

I have copied the `serve-static` code and added a condition to it, you can get it [here](https://gist.github.com/majimboo/094463a89dce660a96e6).

- Download it and save it as `serve-static.js`.
- Include it in your `expressjs` project.
- Modify to your use case.
- Beware untested code.

### Usage

```
var static = require('./serve-static')
// session middleware here
app.use(static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

This should only serve the static files when the `req.session.loggedIn` is `true`.

Of course you can change the condition to anything you want like:

```
if (req.session && req.session.ANYTHING_I_WANT === false && !!someMore)  {
  // skip all the code below (will not serve)
  return next()
}
```

The condition can be found on [line 64 of my serve-static](https://gist.github.com/majimboo/094463a89dce660a96e6#file-serve-static-js-L64) gist.

> **Remember to add the session middleware before using the static middleware.**

Comment: maybe there are way of recreate express?

Comment: @GoncharDenys Let me give you a gist and an example usage. Give me a minute.

Comment: you should probably call next('skip') instead of just letting the connection get GC'd

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove static folders from express. What you can do is use [`res.sendFile`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.sendFile) to send a file as the response. For example:

```
app.get('public/:filename', function(req, res){
  if(user.loggedIn) {
    res.sendFile(req.params[:filename]);
  } else {
    res.status(402).send("Log in to access file");
  }
})
```