# Express.js 4 - use middleware for authentication before static files

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, middleware, static-files

In my `express` app I've set static files to be served from the `/public` directory with this line:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Now I need to add a middleware for authentication before serving the static content and if the user is not authenticated to be redirected to a route for authentication (e.g., `/login`).
I'm not really sure how I have to do it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you didn't specify it, I'm going to assume that you already have some kind of authentication system.

In Express, the order of the middlewares in the code matters: if you want to have middleware 1 executed before middleware 2, you should place them accordingly in your code. Since `express.static` *is* a middleware, if you want authentication before serving your static files you can simply write your authentication middleware before the call to `express.static`

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    if (!userAuthenticated(req)) {
        return res.redirect('/login');
    }
    next();    
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

I am assuming you have a `userAuthenticated` function which is for instance checking if the HTTP requests contains a valid access-token.

[Read more about middlewares.](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)

Comment: Great! Thank you for the solution! I was considering something similar but I wasn't sure for the implementation and if I am able to make such kind of redirect at this point. Thanks again!

Comment: thanks! Your answer helped me to solve the static files question but also to understand better how express middlewares work. Everything makes sense now

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Passport](http://passportjs.org/).

Passport has many authentication strategies.

Here's an example with basic HTTP authentication:

```
var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');
var BasicStrategy = require('passport-http').BasicStrategy;
var db = require('./db');


// Configure the Basic strategy for use by Passport.
//
// The Basic strategy requires a `verify` function which receives the
// credentials (`username` and `password`) contained in the request.  The
// function must verify that the password is correct and then invoke `cb` with
// a user object, which will be set at `req.user` in route handlers after
// authentication.
passport.use(new BasicStrategy(
  function(username, password, cb) {
    db.users.findByUsername(username, function(err, user) {
      if (err) { return cb(err); }
      if (!user) { return cb(null, false); }
      if (user.password != password) { return cb(null, false); }
      return cb(null, user);
    });
  }));


// Create a new Express application.
var app = express();

var authenticate = passport.authenticate('basic', {
  session: false,
  failureRedirect: '/login'
});

app.use(authenticate, express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what kind of authentication you are looking for, but if you just want some login-feature, this is what you need: http://passportjs.org/

It has support for local login strategies, as well as a whole bunch of 3rd party strategies like facebook, twitter, etc.

If you need something else, simpler or self-made, just write a middleware to use before you declare the static endpoint, and call next() if everything checks out, and res.redirect if user needs to retry.