# Why is my Express.js behaving inconsitently when using auth middleware?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, express, jwt

I have an Express.js backend server that serves a public login page and my private react app.

My problem is an inconsistent behaviour of my express server for authentification.
With this I orientated on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21341538/4908844

I have basically three routes:

`http://localhost:4000` -> private

`http://localhost:4000/login/` -> public

`http://localhost:4000/api/auth/` -> public

The entire middleware code can be found at the bottom.

Everything works fine when I am not logged in (no auth-cookie with jwt token available).
If I try to enter `http://localhost:4000` I receive the following console output:

```
Logged  /  GET -- Fri Dec 11 2020 09:52:26 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00)
undefined
{ JsonWebTokenError: jwt must be provided
    at Object.module.exports [as verify] (C:\Users\Development\apps\backend\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:53:17)
    at C:\Users\Development\apps\backend\server.js:90:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Development\apps\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\Development\apps\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at C:\Users\Development\apps\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Development\apps\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\Development\apps\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at cookieParser (C:\Users\Development\apps\backend\node_modules\cookie-parser\index.js:71:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Development\apps\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\Development\apps\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13) name: 'JsonWebTokenError', message: 'jwt must be provided' }
redirect triggered
Logged  /login/  GET -- Fri Dec 11 2020 09:52:26 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00)
```

The code correctly sees that there is no jwt token and cannot verify it - so it redirects back to `/login/`

The code for this is here:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // check for token cookie

    const authCookie = req.cookies["auth-cookie"];
    console.log(authCookie)

    // check jwt token jwt.verify
    jwt.verify(authCookie, jwtSecret, (err, decoded) => {
        // if token is valid
        if (decoded) {
            console.log("valid token")
            next();
        }
        // if token is invalid
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            console.log("redirect triggered")
            res.redirect('/login');
        }
    })
});
```

If I log in with correct username and password I get a http 'auth-cookie' with a jwt inside.
If I then try the same thing again (enter http://localhost:4000 - see above) I receive the following output:

```
Logged  /  GET -- Fri Dec 11 2020 09:57:20 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00)
eyJhbG... (rest of token)
valid token
Logged  /static/css/main.d92f8d30.chunk.css  GET -- Fri Dec 11 2020 09:57:20 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00)
eyJhbG... (rest of token)
valid token
Logged  /static/js/2.77090840.chunk.js  GET -- Fri Dec 11 2020 09:57:20 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00)
eyJhbG... (rest of token)
valid token
Logged  /static/js/main.af5d173b.chunk.js  GET -- Fri Dec 11 2020 09:57:20 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00)
eyJhbG... (rest of token)
valid token
Logged  /static/css/main.d92f8d30.chunk.css.map  GET -- Fri Dec 11 2020 09:57:20 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00)
eyJhbG... (rest of token)
valid token
Logged  /static/js/2.77090840.chunk.js.map  GET -- Fri Dec 11 2020 09:57:20 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00)
eyJhbG... (rest of token)
valid token
Logged  /locales/en/translation.json  GET -- Fri Dec 11 2020 09:57:21 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00)
eyJhbG... (rest of token)
valid token
Logged  /static/js/main.af5d173b.chunk.js.map  GET -- Fri Dec 11 2020 09:57:21 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00)
eyJhbG... (rest of token)
valid token
Logged  /static/media/Logo.8a7963fc.png  GET -- Fri Dec 11 2020 09:57:21 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00)
eyJhbG... (rest of token)
valid token
Logged  /static/media/infButtonHome.e2ebb5ae.png  GET -- Fri Dec 11 2020 09:57:21 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00)
eyJhbG... (rest of token)
valid token
Logged  /static/media/indButtonHome.c3a23e56.png  GET -- Fri Dec 11 2020 09:57:21 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00)
eyJhbG... (rest of token)
valid token
Logged  /static/media/evuButtonHome.7761c048.png  GET -- Fri Dec 11 2020 09:57:21 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00)
eyJhbG... (rest of token)
valid token
Logged  /locales/de/translation.json  GET -- Fri Dec 11 2020 09:57:21 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00)
eyJhbG... (rest of token)
valid token
Logged  /  GET -- Fri Dec 11 2020 09:57:21 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00)
eyJhbG... (rest of token)
valid token
Logged  /static/media/homeBackground.3b448d30.png  GET -- Fri Dec 11 2020 09:57:21 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00)
eyJhbG... (rest of token)
valid token
Logged  /cookie.png  GET -- Fri Dec 11 2020 09:57:21 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00)
eyJhbG... (rest of token)
valid token
Logged  /static/media/ecosystem.1c470787.png  GET -- Fri Dec 11 2020 09:57:21 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00)
eyJhbG... (rest of token)
valid token
Logged  /manifest.json  GET -- Fri Dec 11 2020 09:57:21 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00)
undefined
{ JsonWebTokenError: jwt must be provided
    at Object.module.exports [as verify] (C:\Users\Development\apps\backend\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:53:17)
    at C:\Users\Development\apps\backend\server.js:90:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Development\apps\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\Development\apps\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at C:\Users\Development\apps4ioe_pwa\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Development\apps\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\Development\apps4ioe_pwa\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at cookieParser (C:\Users\Development\apps\backend\node_modules\cookie-parser\index.js:57:14)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Development\apps\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\Development\apps\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13) name: 'JsonWebTokenError', message: 'jwt must be provided' }
redirect triggered
Logged  /login/  GET -- Fri Dec 11 2020 09:57:21 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00)
```

`eyJhbG... (rest of token)` is actually the correct and valid token that I just shortened for privacy reasons.

Why is the code 15 times executing normal and the cookie is transfered correctly but the last time at

```
Logged  /manifest.json  GET -- Fri Dec 11 2020 09:57:21 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00)
undefined
```

I receive an undefinded jwt that was there all the times before?

And additionally why do I receive the logging of redirect

```
redirect triggered
Logged  /login/  GET -- Fri Dec 11 2020 09:57:21 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00)
```

but it is not executing the redirect? My brwoser is still at `http://localhost:4000`

Here is also my complete middleware code:

```
// custom middleware create
const LoggerMiddleware = (req, res, next) =>{
    console.log(`Logged  ${req.url}  ${req.method} -- ${new Date()}`)
    next();
}

app.use(LoggerMiddleware);

app.use(cors({
    origin: [
        'http://localhost:3000',
    ],
    credentials: true,
}))
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use('/login/', express.static('public'))
app.use(function (req, res, next) {

    // check for token cookie

    const authCookie = req.cookies["auth-cookie"];
    console.log(authCookie)
    //console.log(cookies.search("auth-cookie"))
    //const authCookie = cookies.substring

    // get content of the auth cookie
    // check jwt.verify
    jwt.verify(authCookie, jwtSecret, (err, decoded) => {
        // if token is valid
        if (decoded) {
            console.log("valid token")
            next();
        }
        // if token is invalid
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            console.log("redirect triggered")
            res.redirect('/login');
        }
    })
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build/app')))

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Any ideas, why my code is behaving this way?
Why is the jwt token suddenly `undefined` at the end and if that is really the case, why don't I get the redirect like I get in the beginning without a jwt?

Thanks!

EDIT:
The auth-cookie is set with the following code

```
app.get('/api/auth/', function (req, res) {
    // auth header is available
    if (req.headers.authorization) {
        // getting auth header and decoding it for user and password
        const base64encodedAuth = req.headers.authorization.substring(6);
        const encodedAuth = Buffer.from(base64encodedAuth, 'base64').toString('ascii');
        const user = encodedAuth.substring(0, encodedAuth.indexOf(":"));
        const password = encodedAuth.substring(encodedAuth.indexOf(":") + 1);

        // checking if user with correct password exists and return auth-cookie if he does
        if (user in users) {
            console.log("user exists")
            if (users[user] === password) {
                console.log("authenticated!")

                const jwtPayload = {
                    "user": user
                }

                const token = jwt.sign(jwtPayload, jwtSecret)

                res.cookie('auth-cookie', token, {
                    maxAge: 600000,
                    httpOnly: true
                });
                res.sendStatus(200)
            }
            else {
                console.log("wrong password")
                res.sendStatus(401)
            }
        }
        else {
            console.log("wrong user name")
            res.sendStatus(401)
        }
    }
    // no auth header available
    else {
        res.sendStatus(400)
    }
})
```

As hinted by Molda in the comments I checked the DevTools/Network tab. And for the `manifest.json` file there is no cookie tab

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the request in the **DevTools/Network** tab if it has the cookie in the **Request headers/Cookie**? How do you set the `auth-cookie`.

Comment: Please see my updated post. I put the code for setting the auth-cookie at the end. If I check in DevTools/Network tab on `manifest.json` there is no `Cookie` tab like with the others. Do you know why that is?

Comment: Why does it return Status code **302** ??

Comment: I assume the following: As of Wikipedia Code 302 means "The HTTP response status code 302 Found is a common way of performing URL redirection. An HTTP response with this status code will additionally provide a URL in the header field Location." In the location field there is `/login/`. So I guess it just tells me that I will be redirected which is correct if the jwt is not found. But why is there no jwt?